# Click Event of Radio Not Working in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
   <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name='@(string.Format("{0}_{1}", "radioGroup", Model.id))' value="@Model.options[i].value" onclick="next('@(Model.id)','@(nextQid)')" class="check_radio" />
```

In MVC i write above code.
Onclick event not fired in IE8. It works fine in IE9,Chrome.

Comment: How about using the onchange event instead

Comment: i Solved. Actually in javascript function there is trim() which is not  available in IE 7 and it generates error so. so i Just use $.trim("") of jquery.